# Dismissing and Presenting MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am keeping a variable holding the MFMessageComposeViewController instance. If I click "cancel" in the SMS view, I dismiss the MFMessageComposeViewController.

Now if I try to present it again, the view loads but the keyboard is not visible and the view is like in read-only mode.
I tried to instantiate again the variable that I have for the MFMessageComposeViewController. What happens then is that I the view loads correctly, but the keyboard does not show like in the first time I present the view.

Can you help in what am I doing wrong?

Here is how I present the view:

```
messageViewController.body = message;
messageViewController.recipients = [userDefaults.stringForKey("MessageNumber")!];
messageViewController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
self.presentViewController(messageViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

and how I dismiss it:

```
case MessageComposeResultCancelled.value:
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, nil);
//messageViewController = MFMessageComposeViewController();
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

The MessageController must call the method dismissViewControllerAnimated() not your parent ViewController.

```
 messageViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, nil);
```

Comment: my parent view controller is a delegate, so i would expect it to work. i can try your idea nevertheless.